# React adding value to button from callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render: function(){
    var id = 2;

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" ref="id" value={id} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I know that I can add a value to a button using a variable (as above), however I am getting my initial value from a mysql database, which requires a callback function. I was using socket.io to try and get the value:

```
render: function(){
    socket.emit('get_value')
    socket.on('returned_value',  function (value) {
        //does not work
        id = value
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" ref="id" value={id} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The emit works, but socket.on does not. I have also tried to wrap the render in the socket.io method to force it to wait, but it obviously does not work. I have no idea how to get the value from the app.js class to index.js dynamically.

In app.js:

```
socket.on('get_value', function () {
   mysql.getCurrentValue('*', function (result) {
   socket.emit('returned_value', result)
   });
});
```

Trying to include the mysql script directly in index.js (ie mysql = require('mysql.js')) also causes the page not to render, but I dont know why. I works from app.js which is why im using socket.io.

Comment: Put the socket code in the `componentDidMount()` method and set the `id` as state (`this.setState({ id: id });`. Then set the value of the input to `this.state.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a [quick example](http://jsbin.com/mubeho/edit?js,output). Put the socket code in the `componentDidMount()` method and set the `id` as state (`this.setState({ id: id });`. Then set the value of the input to `this.state.id`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    socket.emit('get_value')
    socket.on('returned_value',  function (value) {
      this.setState({id: id});
    }.bind(this); // think you have to bind, didn't test
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <input type="text" ref="id" value={this.state.id} />
    );
  }
```